# Spring Batch: Create an ItemReader that reads an xml file from a web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to create a Spring Batch job that will process an xml file that will be served up through a REST call.

I am trying to use an XML file that's hosted on the internet to test this. The file is located at: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

I downloaded this file locally and am able to convert it to an object and write it, but I don't know how I can do the same without downloading the file locally. This works locally, but how can I specify a URL as the resource for the xml file to read? Thanks :)

launch-context.xml

```
    <batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="100" >
            <batch:chunk reader="CustomPlantReader" writer="writer" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

custom reader bean:

```
    <bean id="CustomPlantReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="PLANT" />
    <property name="resource" value="file:/C:/source/plant_catalog.xml" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="PlantUnmarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="PlantUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="ignoreExtraElements" value="true" />
    <property name="mappingLocation" value="linemapper/mapping.xml" />
</bean>
```

For reference, if anyone wants to see the mapping.xml file this is what it looks like. It maps the xml nodes to a domain object called Plant.java

```
<mapping>
<class name="com.example.project.Plant">
    <map-to xml="PLANT" />

    <field name="common" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="COMMON" node="element"/>
    </field>
    <field name="botanical" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="BOTANICAL" node="element"/>
    </field>
    <field name="zone" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="ZONE" node="element"/>
    </field>
    <field name="light" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="LIGHT" node="element"/>
    </field>
    <field name="price" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="PRICE" node="element"/>
    </field>
    <field name="availability" type="string">
        <bind-xml name="AVAILABILITY" node="element"/>
    </field>

</class></mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StaxEventItemReader` takes a `Resource`.
Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html), you will see that you can easily use a resource that is not on your filesystem. Anything on which you can get an InputStream can probably be converted to a Resource.
The default use an `UrlResource` with a fallback to `ClasspathResource` as far as I remember.

> 4.3.1. UrlResource
>
> The UrlResource wraps a java.net.URL, and may be used to access any object that is normally accessible via a URL, such as files, an
>   HTTP target, an FTP target, etc. All URLs have a standardized String
>   representation, such that appropriate standardized prefixes are used
>   to indicate one URL type from another. This includes file: for
>   accessing filesystem paths, http: for accessing resources via the HTTP
>   protocol, ftp: for accessing resources via FTP, etc.
>   A UrlResource is created by Java code explicitly using the UrlResource constructor, but will often be created implicitly when you
>   call an API method which takes a String argument which is meant to
>   represent a path. For the latter case, a JavaBeans PropertyEditor will
>   ultimately decide which type of Resource to create. If the path string
>   contains a few well-known (to it, that is) prefixes such as
>   classpath:, it will create an appropriate specialized Resource for
>   that prefix. However, if it doesn't recognize the prefix, it will
>   assume the this is just a standard URL string, and will create a
>   UrlResource.

So you can probably just use this:

```
<property name="resource" value="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml" />
```

Comment: I think there's something small I'm missing. When I try to use the URL as you specified I get: `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)`
Do I need to specify a file stream in the tasklet maybe?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by chance?

Comment: Yup! I didnt think it would matter since I could access the xml from my browser, but I tried from a different network and it worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: I have similar problem, can you guys please help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062293/error-encountered-an-error-executing-the-step-org-springframework-batch-item-it  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058880/job-fails-with-input-resource-must-exist-reader-is-in-strict-mode-class-pa

Comment: @user1191081 the 2nd link does not seem to work, I answered to first