# Using Spring batch how to read file from http server

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to read file from HTTP server or how to download file from HTTP server using spring batch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789681/org-springframework-batch-item-itemstreamexception-failed-to-initialize-the-rea)

Comment: use spring integration

Answer (score -1):

This is not a specified Spring Batch problem, just use an pre-step to download your file local (for example via `wget` and System-call) or use an implementation of `ItemStreamReader` which does some http-reading like described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: am getting below error..

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)