# Read csv from REST API in java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How we can read a csv from REST API and process it in java spark,

Basically I am looking for java equivalent code of below scala code

[process-csv-from-rest-api-into-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961433/process-csv-from-rest-api-into-spark)

```
import scala.io.Source._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

var res = fromURL(url).mkString.stripMargin.lines.toList
val csvData: Dataset[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(res).toDS()

val frame = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema",true).csv(csvData)
frame.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use approach mentioned in below link to read in data and add each line in list.

This list can be passed to parallelise()

[Java read CSV file from the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292230/java-read-csv-file-from-the-web)